# Add Attribute Data to Polyline from Point

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes

I have code that is taking a point dataset and converting into lines based on an ID similar to point to Line. It is also creating 32 new fields in the polyline that I want to populate from the the point data.

Here is how my point data is structured
[image]

I want the first point in the line, sorted by PTID, to populate my InvertS1 attributes as seen below, 
[image]

Then my second point in the line would populate the next set of attributes and so on until the line is completed.

I'm having trouble with where populating these fields goes in the code as well as how to structure it.

Here is my code as it is currently, with no population of the fields and it is working as expected.

```
import arcpy, os, types

def convertPoints():
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inPts       = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Input point feature class
outFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #Output polyline feature class
culvertID   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #Culvert ID field
sortField   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #Optional sort field for direction of line
#Date_Added  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) #The date when survey points were received 
closeLine   = False                       #Leaves Line Open

if culvertID in ["", "#"]: culvertID = None

if sortField in ["", "#"]:
    cursorSort = culvertID
else:
    if culvertID:
        cursorSort = culvertID + ";" + sortField
    else:
        cursorSort = sortField

convertPointsToLine(inPts, outFeatures, culvertID, cursorSort, closeLine)

# Add the following fields to the output polyline feature class
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "DateRecieved", "DATE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "Comment", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS1_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS1_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS1_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS1_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS1_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS1_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS1_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS1_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS1_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS1_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS1_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS1_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS1_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS1_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS1_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS2_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS2_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS2_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS2_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "InvertS2_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS2_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS2_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS2_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS2_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "OvertS2_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS2_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS2_PointID", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS2_Northing", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS2_Easting", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "PavementS2_Elevation", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")

def getZM(propType, hasMZ):
    envValue = getattr(arcpy.env, propType).upper()

if envValue in ['ENABLED', 'DISABLED']:
    return envValue
else:
    if hasMZ:
        return "ENABLED"
    else:
        return "DISABLED"

def convertPointsToLine(inPts, outFeatures, culvertID, cursorSort, closeLine):
try:
    # Assign empty values to cursor and row objects
    iCur, sRow, feat = None, None, None

    desc = arcpy.Describe(inPts)
    shapeName = desc.shapeFieldName

    # Create the output feature class
    #
    outPath, outFC = os.path.split(outFeatures)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outPath, outFC, "POLYLINE", "",
                                        getZM("outputMFlag", desc.hasM),
                                        getZM("outputZFlag", desc.hasZ),
                                        inPts)

    # If there is an culvertID, add the equivalent to the output

   # if ID:
    f = arcpy.ListFields(inPts, culvertID)[0]
    fName = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(f.name, outPath)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, fName, f.type, f.precision, f.scale, f.length,
                                f.aliasName, f.isNullable, f.required, f.domain)

    # Open an insert cursor for the new feature class
    #
    iCur = arcpy.InsertCursor(outFeatures)

    # Create an array needed to create features
    #
    array = arcpy.Array()

    # Initialize a variable for keeping track of a feature's ID.
    #
    ID = -1
    fields = shapeName
    if cursorSort:
        fields += ";" + cursorSort

    for sRow in arcpy.gp.SearchCursor(inPts, "", None, fields, cursorSort, arcpy.env.extent):
        pt = sRow.getValue(shapeName).getPart(0)
        if culvertID:
            currentValue = sRow.getValue(culvertID)
        else:
            currentValue = None

        if ID == -1:
            ID = currentValue

        if ID <> currentValue:
            if array.count >= 2:

                # To close, add first point to the end
                #
                if closeLine:
                    array.add(array.getObject(0))

                feat = iCur.newRow()
                if culvertID:
                    if ID: #in case the value is None/Null
                        feat.setValue(culvertID, ID)
                feat.setValue(shapeName, array)
                iCur.insertRow(feat)
            else:
                arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 1059, unicode(ID))

            array.removeAll()

        array.add(pt)
        ID = currentValue

    # Add the last feature
    #
    if array.count > 1:
        # To close, add first point to the end
        #
        if closeLine:
            array.add(array.getObject(0))

        feat = iCur.newRow()
        if culvertID:
            if ID: #in case the value is None/Null
                feat.setValue(culvertID, currentValue)
        feat.setValue(shapeName, array)
        iCur.insertRow(feat)
    else:
        arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 1059, unicode(ID))
    array.removeAll()

except Exception as err:
    import traceback
    arcpy.AddError(
        traceback.format_exception_only(type(err), err)[0].rstrip())

finally:
    if iCur:
        del iCur
    if sRow:
        del sRow
    if feat:
        del feat

    try:
        # Update the spatial index(es)
        #
        r = arcpy.CalculateDefaultGridIndex_management(outFeatures)
        arcpy.AddSpatialIndex_management(outFeatures, r.getOutput(0), r.getOutput(1), r.getOutput(2))
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    convertPoints()
```